# Не работает скрипт "button" JS

Tags: javascript, html

```js
$("button").on("click", function() {
  console.log("clicked!")
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
}

header {
  text-align: center;
  background: url("https://source.unsplash.com/UA741brUQng/1600X900");
  background-size: cover;
  color: white;
}

a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 70px;
}

ul {
  padding: 10px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

img {
  margin: 40px 0px 0px 0px;
  border: 7px solid #FFB858;
  border-radius: 50px;
}

li {
  display: inline;
  padding: 0px 10px 0px 10px;
}

article {
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 900px;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 0px auto;
}

@media(max-width: 600px) {
  body {
    background: #EEC87B;
  }
  h1 {
    font-size: 36px;
  }
  li {
    display: block;
    padding: 5px;
  }
  article {
    width: 80%;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
  <img style="width: 100px" src="https://source.unsplash.com/f0OmyQxntHQ/100X100">
  <h1>Magzhan Sydykov</h1>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">About Me</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">My Projects</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</header>

<article>
  <h2>VHS umami pop-up trust fund</h2>
  <p>Marfa church-key kitsch bicycle rights, 8-bit mixtape cardigan gentrify Echo Park. Street art swag brunch, next level roof party Schlitz hella organic keffiyeh selfies. You probably haven't heard of them polaroid hashtag +1, meggings biodiesel Portland
    High Life cray tumblr retro.</p>
  <button>Like</button>
</article>

<article>
  <h2>Sartorial synth Echo Park, roof party</h2>
  <p>chambray you probably haven't heard of them pour-over viral selvage umami skateboard VHS post-ironic selfies. Wes Anderson gentrify fanny pack twee, bicycle rights bitters blog keffiyeh plaid flannel. Tonx irony cliche sustainable mlkshk bitters. Four
    loko leggings chambray Vice.</p>
  <button>Like</button>
</article>

<article>
  <h2>Forage food truck keytar master cleanse</h2>
  <p>ethical thundercats sustainable locavore quinoa Neutra. Aesthetic tacky sweater single-origin coffee, bicycle rights organic lo-fi street art american apparel ennui four loko ethnic Brooklyn small batch. Forage YOLO polaroid</p>
  <button>Like</button>
</article>
```

Comment: подключи jQuery будет работать

Comment: Спасибо за помощь! Как обычно, только я запостил вопрос, так сразу же решение нашлось само.)

Comment: примите ответ нажав галочку с лево если оно решила вашу проблему

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как и сказал **Demon__ANT** подключите проста `jQuery`

```js
 $("button").on("click", function(){alert("clicked!")});
```

```css
body {
   margin: 0px;
  }

  header {
   text-align: center;
   background: url("pictures/wallpaper.jpg");
   background-size: cover;
   color: white;
   }

  a  {
   color: white;
   text-decoration: none;
   }

  h1 {
   font-size: 70px;
   }

  ul {
    padding: 10px;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
     }

  img {
    margin: 40px 0px 0px 0px;
    border: 7px solid #FFB858;
    border-radius: 50px;

    }
    
  li {
      display: inline;
      padding: 0px 10px 0px 10px;
     }

  article {
       width: 80%;
       max-width: 900px;
       padding: 20px;
       margin: 0px auto;
        }

       @media(max-width: 600px){
        body{
         background: #EEC87B;
        }

        h1 {
          font-size: 36px; 
         }
        
        li {
           display: block;
           padding: 5px;
         } 

         article {
          width: 80%;
         }
       }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header> 
  <img style="width: 100px" src="pictures/myPhoto.jpg">
  <h1>Magzhan Sydykov</h1>
  <ul>
   <li><a href="#">About Me</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">My Projects</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
 </header>

 <article>
    <h2>VHS umami pop-up trust fund</h2>
    <p>Marfa church-key kitsch bicycle rights, 8-bit mixtape cardigan gentrify Echo Park. Street art swag brunch, next level roof party Schlitz hella organic keffiyeh selfies. You probably haven't heard of them polaroid hashtag +1, meggings biodiesel Portland High Life cray tumblr retro.</p>
    <button>Like</button>
    </article>
    
    <article>
    <h2>Sartorial synth Echo Park, roof party</h2>
    <p>chambray you probably haven't heard of them pour-over viral selvage umami skateboard VHS post-ironic selfies. Wes Anderson gentrify fanny pack twee, bicycle rights bitters blog keffiyeh plaid flannel. Tonx irony cliche sustainable mlkshk bitters. Four loko leggings chambray Vice.</p>
    <button>Like</button>
    </article>
    
    <article>
    <h2>Forage food truck keytar master cleanse</h2>
    <p>ethical thundercats sustainable locavore quinoa Neutra. Aesthetic tacky sweater single-origin coffee, bicycle rights organic lo-fi street art american apparel ennui four loko ethnic Brooklyn small batch. Forage YOLO polaroid</p>
    <button>Like</button>
   </article>
```